# How to pass a value between controller actions

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview, tempdata

I have a page with several partial views.  Each one contains a Ajax.BeginForm and all post to the same controller to perform various lookups.  The ActionResult returns a value that I need to store for use in another ActionResult on the same page, same controller.

I've tried TempData, ViewBag, ViewData but the value is not being passed.

I have a typical controller action like so:

```
    public ActionResult ExistingLogin(AMSIdentifyInputModel_ExistingLogin model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
                int? entityNumber = (from s in statebarDB.IMail
                                        where s.USERID == model.oldUsername
                                        && s.PASSWORD == model.oldPassword
                                        select s.ENTITY_NUMBER).FirstOrDefault();

                if (entityNumber != null && entityNumber != 0)
                {
                    ViewData["entityNumber"] = entityNumber;
                    return Json(new { result = 1, message = "User found." });
                }
        }
    }
```

and another partial view that submits to a different action and tries to read that entityNumber with no success:

```
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateAccount(AMSIdentify_RegisterInputModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
                this.userAccountService.UpdateEntityID(account, (int)ViewData["entityNumber"]);
. . .
```

Is there another way to store a value with the view temporarily?

Comment: Tempdata is the only one option that can work for you as in your question you are using Viewdata which lost its value on redirect...but tempdata can retain its value for one redirect...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming entityNumber is just an ID, and not a massively important security hole or enormous gigabyte-long number:

Assignment:

```
Session["entityNumber"] = entityNumber;
```

Reference:

```
(int)Session["entityNumber"];
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 other ways to store data in a temporary manner that is on the frontend side.
1. You can use **LocalStorage** functionality given by HTML5 using javascript or JQuery.
2. You can store the value in a model value and at the time of execution, you can pass the value with the variable, in javascript side.

On the backend side, TempData, ViewBag, ViewData are loaded at the time of page load and hence they are not able to change as per our need.

Thus we can use **Session** if you need to use it in backend side.
Also you can use the **Cookies** too.